# JSON API V1 Creating Nested Resources

Tags: json-api

I am implementing a JSON API V1 compliant API using Grape API that uses AR as the ORM. I am a little confused on the format to create nested resources / relationships. It looks like we need to create one resource at a time and can link to exisitng resources. But we can't lets say create records for a `has many` relationship int he same request.

My situation:  There is the `Donation` modal. It has many `Split`s. A split belong to a `Fund`. I need to create a donation with multiple splits.

**Question**: How can I structure the API according to the [JSON:API](https://jsonapi.org/format/) recommendations?

Going through the documentation few times, I am thinking I can't make the donation in one API call and will have to create each resource separately and may be run a final commit to to trigger the donation.

Step 1: Create the donation - assume returns ID 100

POST `/api/v1/donations`

```
{ type: "donation", data: { comments: "abc" } }
```

Step 2: Create Split 1

POST `/api/v1/splits`

```
{
  type: "split",
  data: { amount: 100_00 },
  relationships: {
    data: [{ type: "fund", id: 5 }, { type: "donation", id: 100 }]
  }
}
```

Finally: trigger the donation with some thing like

PATCH `/api/v1/donations/100`

```
{
  type: "donation"
  data: { 
    state: "process"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to create it in one request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON:API specification does not support creating, updating or deleting multiple resources in one request in v1.0, which is the current stable version.

The upcoming v1.1 is planned to support [Extensions](https://jsonapi.org/format/1.1/#extensions), which allow to extend the base specification. There is a proposal of a [Atomic Operations extension](https://github.com/json-api/json-api/pull/1437) provided by one of the maintainers of the specification. It's [planned to be released with v1.1](https://github.com/json-api/json-api/issues/1435) as official extension.

Comment: Interesting... but at the moment, we will have to proceed with separate api calls.... thank you very much... that doc is a lot to read...